# run the web url based on local linux server instead of web server

Tags: linux

sorry if I made any wrong describing becasue I am not so familiar in this field. I am currently run a website on the webserver, if I have a local linux server, so if I want to move the url to my local linux server, How to conficure that? can anybody give me some advice and help me, thanks a lot! I use php on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand correctly, but perhaps this will help. Edit your host file on your computer, so that you can redirect a domain (example.com) to an IP address of your choice (127.0.0.1 for local host).

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)

Comment: Thanks. Do you mean if i know my local IP. I can  redirect the domain to my local IP, instead of local host?

Comment: Sure, if your local linux server runs on 192.168.2.102 for example, you can enter that in your host file.